# Adding a unique id to every model prior to creation in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 5.1
Ruby 2.4.1
mysql
```

In my controllers/concerns/jhm_unique_id_gen_helper.rb, I have:

```
require 'time'

module JHMUniqueIdGenHelper

  def self.included(base)
    base.primary_key = 'id'
    base.before_create :assign_id
  end

  private
  def assign_id
    time = Time.now
    self.id = "#{time.to_i}#{time.usec}" if self.id.blank?
  end

end
```

A typical migration (using users as an example), has the following in it:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, id: false do |t|
      t.string :id, limit: 16, primary: true, null: false
```

In my app/controllers/application_controller.rb, I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include JHMUniqueIdGenHelper
```

Is there anything else I need to do, to insure that the id is generated and added to the model, prior to creation?

Comment: Why not rely on the [rails mechanism](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/04/rails-5-provides-application-config-to-use-UUID-as-primary-key.html)?

Comment: Because I would like to use a timestamp "based" id system, and will be adding another identifier to it, probably the model name.

Comment: How many processes of the app will you be running? It's unlikely but possible to get a conflict if it is more than one, which would then conflict with it being the primary key. The DBMS should prevent it but you'd get an error.

Comment: According to this [article](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/), your migration won't work. Would be interested to know your results though. And second @ulferts that you might get duplicate timestamp.

Comment: I will check out the article. Duplicates are not going to happen, even with threads, because it's on a per model basis, and this field is the primary, so the DB will not create a duplicate. That is if miraculously, all the threads were generating an id, for the same model, at the exact microsecond resolution

Comment: Ok, I read the article. For starters, it seems to me that using mysql syntax is a bad idea. Second, this is what I based my work on http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key

Comment: If you read carefully, the recommendation there is to not define primary key in migration, but only define the necessary constraints and index to mimic a primary key. But that's based on rails4. Would like to know if your migration works on rails5.

Comment: Why do you want a timestamp based id? What re you trying to gain out of this? You could keep the numeric ids, but youse a different "slug" in the urls.

Comment: `User.first.created_at.to_i` returns the *number of seconds since the Unix epoch*. Therefore your "custom id" could be computed after save (as a DB trigger for faster result?), or in a Rails way `before_save { self.my_custom_id = "#{class.underscore}__#{DateTime.current.to_i}" }`. This shows how you are trying to reinvent something Rails and the DB handles very well. A.K.A primary key `id`